# Python get array line +1

Tags: python, arrays

I have this array in Python:

```
['', '/ISk5\\2ME382-1003', '', '0-0:96.1.1(4B414C37303035303932383736393132)', '1-0:1.8.1(00663.661*kWh)', '1-0:1.8.2(00643.213*kWh)', '1-0:2.8.1(00000.036*kWh)', '1-0:2.8.2(00000.028*kWh)', '0-0:96.14.0(0001)', '1-0:1.7.0(0000.12*kW)', '1-0:2.7.0(0000.00*kW)', '0-0:17.0.0(0999.00*kW)', '0-0:96.3.10(1)', '0-0:96.13.1()', '0-0:96.13.0()', '0-1:24.1.0(3)', '0-1:96.1.0(3234313537303032393736363636323132)', '0-1:24.3.0(130713200000)(00)(60)(1)(0-1:24.2.1)(m3)', '(00966.040)', '0-1:24.4.0(1)']
```

This is simply this data transformed into an array (data is slightly different):

```
/ISk5\2ME382-1003
0-0:96.1.1(4B414C37303035313039)
1-0:1.8.1(00180.724*kWh)
1-0:1.8.2(00001.416*kWh)
1-0:2.8.1(00000.000*kWh)
1-0:2.8.2(00000.000*kWh)
0-0:96.14.0(0001)
1-0:1.7.0(0000.42*kW)
1-0:2.7.0(0000.00*kW)
0-0:17.0.0(0999.00*kW)
0-0:96.3.10(1)
0-0:96.13.1()
0-0:96.13.0()
0-1:24.1.0(3)
0-1:96.1.0(32383031313030313231)
0-1:24.3.0(120911010000)(00)(60)(1)(0-1:24.2.1)(m3)
(00007.646)
0-1:24.4.0(1)
!
```

Now, I'm only interested in some lines. I'm able to extract all the data I want, except for one line.
More specifically, this line: (00007.646)

This line is always the first line after 0-1:24.3.0(120911010000)(00)(60)(1)(0-1:24.2.1)(m3).

In other words, I want python to find this line, and give me the output of the next line.

How do I achieve this? My code:

```
for line in stack:
    if line[0:9] == "1-0:1.8.1":
        a = line[10:18]
    elif line[0:9] == "1-0:1.8.2":
        b = line[10:18]
    elif line[0:9] == "1-0:1.7.0":
        c = line[10:17]
    elif line[0:10] == "0-1:24.3.0":
        d = line[+1]
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: The `line` variable refers to the current line, you can't just do `line[+1]`. You'll have to get the next line from your `stack` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick fix;

```
for i, line in enumerate(stack):
    if line[0:10] == "0-1:24.3.0":
        print stack[i+1]
```

The [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function allows iteration over `stack` whilst providing both the element and its index. Here the `i` represents the index of current `line` in the `stack`.